# ¿ Como incluir un archivo js externo a mi proyecto angular?

Tags: angular

Soy novato en el angular y tengo el siguiente  problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluí una línea en el *index* con la ruta donde  se encuentra  el  archivo *estilos.js*: **src/assets/js/estilos.js**.

Así mismo, lo agregué al archivo **angular.json**, sin embargo, el error persiste. Tengo un *snippet* que me ayuda a localizar los archivos, por lo tanto, no puede ser por la ruta porque es correcta.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo coloca

```
assets/js/estilos.js
```

Comment: @Kendall Esta es la recomendación que debes seguir.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, llevo casi todo el día buscando una solución y la encontré .